# Polymer Core Scaffold - Set width to change at

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How would you change the width that a core scaffold would resize at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using Core-Media-Query. In your case you would use Core Media Query with Core Scaffold's responsiveWidth attribute.

From the documentation:
`<core-media-query query="max-width: 640px" queryMatches="{{responsiveWidth}}"></core-media-query>`

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-media-query

Answer (score 3):

You can just set the `responsiveWidth` attribute of the `core-scaffold`. You don't really need `core-media-query` for this example.

```
<core-scaffold responsiveWidth="400px">
  ...
</core-scaffold>
```